# Ubuntu freeze at login page, no mouse and no keyboard response, blinking at tty login as well

Tags: nvidia, login, tty

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 installed and everything was working properly. I have an Nvidia Quadro GPU and I was in the process of installing my nvidia driver and then cuda toolkit. The already installed driver was 390. Since it couldn't support cuda 10.1; thus, I had to reinstall it.

Just to let you know, I already updated grub by adding `nomodeset` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Currently, I can only get access to the recovery mode. The GUI log-in is frozen; my keyboard and mouse do not work there at all; I couldn't even switch to `tty`. I tried this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all` in the recovery mode, and the only thing that changed is that I can now access `tty` mode. However, the screen keeps blinking and does not allow me to enter my password correctly.

Note that, I followed all the instructions provided by Nvidia itself to do the installation using Runfile. However, now I am totally stuck; I tried many things on-line but no success so far.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check to see if Wayland is enabled - some nvidia drivers don't like Wayland enabled because they don't provide the features it needs, and you get stuck in gdm stopping and starting. You should be able to disable Wayland in gdm3 via editing  `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

2. Try booting with `nofb nomodeset nosplash` as kernel options
   ... you may be able to back off on this afterwards, but I find it can help with nvidia driver problems
3. Try purging and/or reinstalling the nvidia and cuda packages you need

I don't have specific experience with Cuda or nvidia-390, but the nvidia-340 I run is very temperamental and I find the above things help to get me back on track.

Comment: I did this, but it did not solve the problem. It still exists.